# SecurityException reading picture from Android gallery

Tags: android, image, security, exception, gallery

I am getting a image from gallery and send to my remote server. Next, I save the image path into my shared preferences. This works well.
After some time, when I try recover the image from saved path and show in my image view I get this exception in the line:

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), fileUri);
```

Some times, the code works, but after some time I get this exception.

My exception is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: net.techabout.medappointment, PID: 4160
                  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{9922e7c 4160:net.techabout.medappointment/u0a105} (pid=4160, uid=10105) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or 
android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1468)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1088)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:942)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:662)
                      at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:866)
                      at net.techabout.medappointment.ConfigurationFragment.onCreateView(ConfigurationFragment.java:115)
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

Here is my code:

```
private Uri fileUri;
String pathimg;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
ImageView imageView;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.configuationfrag, container, false);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Common.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pathimg = pref.getString("imagepath", "");
        fileUri = Uri.parse(pathimg);

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), fileUri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Button buttonChoose = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonChooseImage);
        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });

        Button buttonupload = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
        buttonupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (bitmap != null) new UploadImage().execute();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
        }

    }
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                pathimg=filePath.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the framework only grants temporal access to the image URI.
If you want to continue to use the URI you have to request a persistent permission, execute the following before storing the URI to the shared preferences:

```
final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
        & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
// Check for the freshest data.
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
```

For more details have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#permissions).

Comment: takePersistableUriPermission requires api 19. Is there some solution to api 15?

Comment: The Storage Access Framework causing this security measurement was introduced with API level 19. On earlier API levels the framework grants permanent access to the URIs exposed over the intent.
Are you experiencing the issue on API levels lower than 19?

Comment: I didnt tested in api <19. I only have seen the ide warning. Another question: Does this intent can be that returned in onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) or do I have the original intent requiring the image?

Comment: You can use the intent returned by onActivityResult. It should be also sufficient to only pass Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and / or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION (without intent.getFlags()), but the documentation does not exactly specify which flags are expected at this point.